# Live streaming audio in a HTML5 canvas/page?

Tags: c#, javascript, audio, canvas, live-streaming

I've created a live video stream using jpeg images converted to a base64 strings which are sent via websockets to a HTML5 canvas. It works pretty well. I've also captured the mouse cursor/buttons and any keydowns to simulate a remote desktop. The images are captured and sent to the sockets in C#.

I now want to somehow stream live audio to the page/canvas so it has all the features of a remote desktop app. Does anyone know how I would go about this and which file format to use? Is it possible to convert the audio to a base64 string and send it that way? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `canvas` is an immediate-mode drawing surface. It has no audio capabilities at all. You might be looking for the `audio` element.

Answer (score 1):

Try use [Web Audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html).

Description & example on [Html5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)

Supported by Chrome & Safari.

Comment: Web Audio is not currently supported by all browsers.

Comment: @BjornRoche supported by Chrome & Safari

Answer (score 1):

You can play the audio stream using the `audio` html5 element.

To cover support for most of the commonly used browsers you will have to stream in at least 2 formats, MP3 and OGG for example.

[image]

For streaming audio (OGG/MP3) you can use an [Icecast server](http://www.icecast.org/).

Here's an example of `audio` tag usage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Audio tag test!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio autoplay="true">
            <source src="http://radio.hbr1.com:19800/ambient.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
            <source src="http://stream1.gameowls.com:8000/bitwave.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

The audio tag plays the first source that the browser can handle.